# How to stop the child from inheriting the parent opacity

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am having trouble to figure out how to stop child elements from inheriting parent opacity.

I know this has been answered before, setting the background instead of opacity values. But my scenario is different in the sense that I have to use fade in effect in my sticky headers that contain the child elements.

When I add fade in, the children too gets the same effect.

Here is some test code:

```js
$('.nav-items').css('opacity', '0.3');

var top_nav = $("body, html").scrollTop();

(function () {
    var $win = $(window);

    $win.on('scroll', function () {

        var header = $(".nav-items");
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 40) {
            if (!header.data('faded')) header.data('faded', 1).not('nav-item li').stop(true).fadeTo(400, 1);
        } else if (header.data('faded')) {
            header.data('faded', 0).stop(true).fadeTo(400, 0.3);
        }
    });
}).call(this);
```

```css
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.nav-items {
    font-weight: 900;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
}
.nav-items ul {
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.nav-items ul li {
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px 45px;
    width: 19%;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #fff;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.nav-items ul li.bigger {
    cursor: default;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    width: 20%;
    padding: 0;
    height: inherit;
    position: relative;
    top: 15px;
    /* vertical-align: bottom; */
}
.nav-items ul li.bigger img {
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav-items">
    <ul>
        <li id="l_1">How it Works</li>
        <li id="l_2">How to be a driver</li>
        <li id="l_3">The Community</li>
        <li id="l_4">Contact Us</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div>Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem</div>
```

Comment: I eagerly open but no code

Comment: can you please show your code in code snippet tool?

Comment: guys ...thanks for responding so fast.

Comment: The code snippet is here  http://jsfiddle.net/10bo1me5/

Comment: Please add code into your questions

Answer (score 1):

You cannot stop layers from inheriting opacity. The only workaround is to set rgb background colors. If child elements inherit this too, you can simply override this by using css.

```
/* Fallback for web browsers that don't support RGBa */
background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
/* RGBa with 0.6 opacity */
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
/* For IE 5.5 - 7*/
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000, endColorstr=#99000000);
/* For IE 8*/
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99000000,endColorstr=#99000000)";
```

Comment: Hosch Nok - Sir, the problem is that I am not able to utilise the fade animation on my sticky header if I dont use opacity. Although , I myself hate to use opacity to a great extent. But in this case I am helpless. I need to use  opacity instead of background color

Comment: This is a fact. To find another workaround you have to post sample code.

Comment: I have already posted it . Re-posting the link for you http://jsfiddle.net/10bo1me5/

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want an overlay effect on the menu when it is in the top of the window; Just **add a separate overlay element inside the menu** and add the effect to that-- instead of targeting it's parent element

> ```
> <div id="overlay"></div>
>
> #overlay {
>     position: absolute;
>     height: 100%;
>     width: 100%;
>     background:black;
>     z-index:-1;
>     opacity:0.3;
> }
> ```

**http://jsfiddle.net/10bo1me5/3/**

### Updated code

```js
var top_nav = $("body, html").scrollTop();

(function () {
    var $win = $(window);

    $win.on('scroll', function () {

        var header = $("#overlay");
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 40) {

            if (!header.data('faded'))

            header.data('faded', 1).not('nav-item li').stop(true).fadeTo(400, 1);

        } else if (header.data('faded')) {
            header.data('faded', 0).stop(true).fadeTo(400, 0.3);
        }



    });
}).call(this);
```

```css
#overlay {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background:black;
    z-index:-1;
    opacity:0.3;
}
.nav-items {
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-weight: 900;
    /*background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);*/
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
}
.nav-items ul {
    max-width: 960px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.nav-items ul li {
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px 45px;
    width: 19%;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #fff;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.nav-items ul li.bigger {
    cursor: default;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    width: 20%;
    padding: 0;
    height: inherit;
    position: relative;
    top: 15px;
    /* vertical-align: bottom; */
}
.nav-items ul li.bigger img {
    height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav-items">
    <div id="overlay"></div>
    <ul>
        <li id="l_1">How it Works</li>
        <li id="l_2">How to be a driver</li>
        <li id="l_3">The Community</li>
        <li id="l_4">Contact Us</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div>Lorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem Ipsum Lorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem IpsumLorem Ipsum</div>
```